# Unable to connect to Firebird server from android

Tags: android, connection, firebird, jaybird

I'm using Jaybird to connect to Firebird sql, my app was connected normally. But today I can't connect.

The only change I made was to execute the auto corrector in inspector, in android studio. I have no idea what is causing this error.

```
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544472. No message for code 335544472 found.
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:123)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractDriver.connect(AbstractDriver.java:126)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at br.cardapionewpointer.TestaConn.doInBackground(TestaConn.java:42)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at br.cardapionewpointer.TestaConn.doInBackground(TestaConn.java:20)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ Caused by: org.firebirdsql.gds.GDSException: No message for code 335544472 found.
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.readStatusVector(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2092)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.receiveResponse(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2042)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.internalAttachDatabase(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:457)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.iscAttachDatabase(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:411)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnection.<init>(FBManagedConnection.java:105)
05-06 10:55:58.067  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(FBManagedConnectionFactory.java:490)
05-06 10:55:58.077  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBStandAloneConnectionManager.allocateConnection(FBStandAloneConnectionManager.java:69)
05-06 10:55:58.077  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:120)
05-06 10:55:58.077  16653-16755/br.cardapionewpointer W/System.err﹕ ... 10 more
```

My class:

```
public class TestaConn extends AsyncTask<Integer,Object,Integer> {
    private final Activity activity;
    private int opt;
    public TestaConn(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... bt) {
        opt = bt[0];
        try{
            Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try{
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("user", "xx");
            props.setProperty("password", "xx");
            props.setProperty("encoding", "WIN1252");
            DBLiteConnection bdl = new DBLiteConnection(activity);
            String ip = bdl.searchip();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql://" + ip + "", props);
            String sSql = "SELECT CD_CHAVE FROM TAB_PARAM";
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sSql);
            if(rs.next())
            {
                rs.close();
                return 1;
            }
            rs.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Integer i) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 335544472 = _Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login._ (this might also indicate that you haven't installed the driver correctly, as there is a mapping of error codes to error message included in the driver)

Answer (score 2):

As implied by my comment from yesterday, the error means that your username and/or password is incorrect (error 335544472 = *Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.*). I don't see how this could be caused by a format/layout change.

Either your username or password has been changed (in your code or on the server), or you are connecting to a different Firebird server than you expect.

This error could also happen if you attempt to connect to a Firebird 3 (beta/RC) server without setting up support for legacy authentication. See also [Jaybird and Firebird 3.0 Beta 2](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/wiki/Jaybird-and-Firebird-3.0-beta-2).

You might also want to check the install for Jaybird for android, as it seems to be missing the error message properties file.